# How to get device id from a native iOS app by using worklight native api

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any way to get device id from a native iOS app by using Worklight native api?

Javascript client-side API has WL.Device.getID function. But I didn't find a similar one in Objective-C client-side API.

Worklight version 6.1

Comment: What are you using the Device ID for? Are you attempting to get the UID of the device or are you attempting to get the device token for push notifications? Also here is a list of all the Objective C client side APIs for Worklight:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/wl_objcref_ios.pdf

Comment: I'd like to call rest services of application center with device id, like: http://localhost:9080/applicationcenter/service/device/41A05578-8DEA-430B-9FB7-57D929058766

Comment: I think I found it:

#import "WLDeviceAuthManager.h"


NSString *devID = [[WLDeviceAuthManager sharedInstance] 
    

NSLog(@"Device id is: %@", devID);

Comment: @user2236002, did it in fact solve your issue? If so, could you please write it as an Answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it:

```
#import "WLDeviceAuthManager.h"

NSString *devID = [[WLDeviceAuthManager sharedInstance] getWLUniqueDeviceId];
NSLog(@"Device id is: %@", devID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 Solution

```
let deviceID = WLDeviceAuthManager.sharedInstance().getWLUniqueDeviceId() 

print(deviceID)
```